# Unable to get window kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16)
[GCC 9.2.1 20200306]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds (img_pygame, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
pygame - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pygame.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pygame

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

I installed ubuntu on termux then by using anlinux I installed its desktop environment running on vncserver.I am a root user.After downloading kivy I got the error.
I tried

```
apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0
```

and

```
apt-get install -y \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
```

This is my code(actually I was testing)

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App


class EApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hi")

EApp().run()
```

Nothing is working.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing all the dependencies using:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy-deps.sdl2 kivy-deps.glew 
pip install kivy-deps.gstreamer 
pip install kivy-deps.angle 
pip install –-upgrade kivy
```

Comment: it says could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.sdl2

Comment: You could instead try doing all this in a real Ubuntu system instead of termux. Termux is not good for doing app development as there are many dependencies which will never be satisfied on an android.

Comment: what should i do in android?